# Appium update on Ubuntu

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I had installed Appium on my Ubuntu machine using

```
 npm install -g appium
```

However, now I need to upgrade it to a newer version say 0.18.2 or a level below than Appium 1.0.0.

```
 npm update -g appium
```

Installs Appium 1.0.0 which I don't want as if now.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

To install specific version, let's say 1.4.0, you can use:
    `npm install -g appium@1.4.0`

Ok, I should explain why I recommended `install` instead of `update` in this case. 0.18.2 is the previous to 1.0.0 version and it cannot be installed via `update` if you already using a newer version.

In case of 1.4.0 version you don't need to declare the version via @1.4.0 since it's a current stable version,  you can simply use `npm install -g appium` to install it.

You should declare version with `@0.18.2` if you want to install old 0.18.2 version via npm, for example.

Answer (score 1):

To install a different version of appium, you need to uninstall the current version first.

```
npm uninstall -g appium
```

Then you can install a specific version by running this command e.g.

```
npm install -g appium@1.4.16
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this command to install otherwise you will receive permission error

```
sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```